# What can cause FindControl() to throw a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, nullreferenceexception, findcontrol

I have a user control I'm building (ASP.NET 3.5, using C#).

This control is largely based on another, similar control (cut & paste inheritance, unfortunately, but there's no easy way to abstract this).  The lines that are giving me trouble are directly copied from the other control, as is the majority of the display.

The relevant lines of code are as follows:

```
Panel pnlForm = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlForm");
Literal ltrAvailableCount = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrAvailableCount");

DropDownList drpLanguage = (DropDownList)pnlForm.FindControl("drpLanguage");
DropDownList drpShipTo = (DropDownList)pnlForm.FindControl("drpShipTo");
HiddenField hdnAvailableProductId = (HiddenField)pnlForm.FindControl("hdnAvailableProductId");

DropDownList drpQuantity = (DropDownList)pnlForm.FindControl("drpQuantity");
HiddenField hdnSelectedStyle = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnSelectedStyle");
Label lblStyleName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblSelectedStyle");
```

**`pnlForm` in the above is found correctly, as is `ltrAvailableCount`.**

If I skip down to `drpQuantity`, it and the following lines work fine.  However, when I run the lines for `drpLanguage`, `drpShipTo`, or `hdnAvailableProductId` `FindControl` throws a `NullReferenceException`.

I do not mean it returns 'null' and I try to access a property of the returned object, the method `FindControl` throws the exception.  According to the MSDN library, this isn't possible - `FindControl` doesn't list anything as a potential thrown error, it just says that if it can't find the Control, it returns null.

What can cause `FindControl` to NullReferenceException?

-----------------Edit---------------

I should also mention that if I run any of the three problematic lines in the immediate window, I get the correct results. I can also see the controls in the `ControlCollection` of `pnlForm` when I inspect it while debugging.

-----------------2nd Edit-------------------

Just to confirm, I added another line:
    DropDownList notThere = (DropDownList)pnlForm.FindControl("notHere");
The control `notHere` is not anywhere on the page.  The above line compiles (of course) and when I run the debugger, it runs fine.  The cast goes fine.  The variable `notThere` simply is null.

**The underlying cause of this issue is NOT FindControl failing to find the controls and trying to cast null to a DropDownList or other Control**

Comment: Are you sure pnlForm is not null? Double check that while debugging.

Comment: are you sure it isn't that one of the objects you are calling FindControl on is null?

Comment: Imagine FindControl() returns `null`, will your cast to a `DropDownList` work? I'm just typing what I'm thinking...

Comment: @jrummell & Robert Levy - Yes.  As I stated in the question.

Comment: You should post the repeater and it's templates as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is NOT FindControl that's causing the problem.

The way you've got it coded it's performing two operations on one line - FindControl() and then the cast to the control datatype.  It's the cast that's bombing, because the results of the FindControl call is a null value, and you're attempting to cast null to a control.

This one bit me many times, so I learned to code it as

```
object oDropDown1 = pnlForm.FindControl("DropDown1");

// then check if oDrowpDown 1 is null and cast if it's safe.

if(oDropDown1 != null)
{
   // here it's safe to cast.
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the case - this pattern is used throughout our project, and in every other case, we've seen it do the cast fine (though the dropdownlist/label/control is null).  Besides, if it were an invalid cast, surely it would throw an InvalidCastException, not a NullReferenceException?

Comment: I modified the code to look like your example, and it returned an object that the debugger saw as a DropDownList.  After the null check, the cast failed.

Comment: OK, so at least you know it's the cast that's failing and not FindControl()... So now you can look in the right place.

Comment: So now I have to figure out why casting an object that is of type DropDownList to a DropDownList throws a NullReferenceException...Great.  From one impossible problem to another :)

Comment: Accepted this answer, as it put me on the path to a solution.

Comment: @Jeff - Thanks.  Out of curiosity, what WAS the solution?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure that out yet, actually, but it's only occurring with a single test account.  After dumping 3-4 man hours into it, my team decided it wasn't worth tracking down unless it occurred again during testing (with other accounts)

Answer (score 7):

casting `null` to a DropDownList will result in an exception.

if `pnlForm.FindControl("drpQuantity")` returns `null` you cannot cast it ;)

however this will work:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList drpQuantity = 
   pnlForm.FindControl("drpQuantity") as System.Web.UI.WebControlsDropDownList;

if(drpQuantity!=null){
   //use drpQuantity here
}
```

The as operator is used to perform conversions between compatible type, The as operator is like a cast except that it yields null on conversion failure instead of raising an exception.

**anyway**, the use of `findcontrol` is only intended for *data-generated controls*, in all other cases use an `interface` (-implementation) to communicate with controls on usercontrols.

IMHO `findcontrol` is a feature that is abused globally.... ( kittens are killed for using it )

Comment: This is being used within the ItemCommand for a repeater, is that what you mean by data-generated?  Also, these lines are from the code-behind of the UserControl, not to access it from a containing page.

Comment: DropDownList drpLanguage = pnlForm.FindControl("drpLanguage") as DropDownList;  This fails as well, with the same exception.  When I attempted to run the modified code suggested by David Stratton, I examined the object FindControl returned for this line - it was not null...so the cast of a DropDownList to a DropDownList is failing.

Comment: UPDATE: added System.Web.UI.WebControls as a namespace to it, perhaps DropDownList is not System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownLIst

Comment: Sensible to think so, but I checked and it is.  Also, see my '2nd edit' above, I intentionally added a line where FindControl would return null and cast it to DropDownList, and it DIDN'T fail.

Answer (score 0):

You get a NullReferenceException, of it does not find a (the) control (you were looking for)

try:

```
DropDownList drpLanguage = (DropDownList)(pnlForm.FindControl("drpLanguage"));
DropDownList drpShipTo = (DropDownList)(pnlForm.FindControl("drpShipTo"));
HiddenField hdnAvailableProductId = (HiddenField)(pnlForm.FindControl("hdnAvailableProductId"));
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx  No, you don't.  It returns null, not the same as throwing a NRE.

Comment: if you try to cast it, then you get NRE